# Disable the HTML5 information from YouTube Embedded Video

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, youtube

I have a YouTube video embedded on my page. I want to disable the option for my users to right click the video and grab the URL.

[image]

```
<?php
echo '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/DZGINaRUEkU' 
. '?&rel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>';
?>
```

How can I do this? I have already disabled as many possible options as I could Google. Please help

Comment: Unless Youtube added an option for it, I'm guessing you can't, as you have no control over the iframe.

Comment: @Drakes - disabling right-click isn't really an option in a cross-origin iFrame

Comment: OP can still throw a transparent div over it and catch clicks. He could also add a bounty to that question.

Comment: I'm guessing just disabling everything with an overlay or even pointer-events isn't an option. I already tried it [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1mzfqh45/) and now there's no way to play, stop or pause the video.

Comment: is there a good use case to prevent getting the video URL ? It's not hard to get it by (1) page source,  (2) page information, (3) dev tools, (4) .... It's not worth the effort IMO.

Comment: The URL is in a variable. I'm sure a developer can grab the URL, but I'm trying to make it a bit harder for anyone to come and grab it.